# If James Baxter gives me a Creeper can I discard it

Tags: fluxx

In Adventure Time Fluxx, the James Baxter action card has each player draw a card, and causes all Creepers in play to be discarded.

If my drawn card is a Creeper (which is immediately put on the table and replaced with another card), is it immediately discarded?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at the text on the card you will notice that the instructions are broken up into 3 sections. What this says to me is that first everyone will draw a card and if they get a creeper they will put it into play and draw a replacement card. Once everyone has drawn the card the next section will happen which causes all creepers in play to be discarded. So that will mean any creeper that is drawn as part of this action will also be discarded as part of this action.

If the action was not to discard the creepers already in play it most likely would have come before the draw step or would have been included in the wording of the draw step.

> All Players draw a card.
>
> All Creepers in play are immediately discarded
>
> All Hand and Keeper Limit Rules are immediately discarded

Text came from a picture on this [site](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1428203/adventure-time-fluxx-detailed-review)

Answer (score 4):

[Joe W's answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/33702/7843) is correct.

In an answer to my email from Andrew Looney:

My Question:

> James Baxter says:
>   "All players draw a card. All Creepers in play are
>   immediately discarded."
>
> If I drew a Creeper from James Baxter I
>   would put it in to play.  Does the discard of creepers happen before
>   or after I put my new creeper into play?

Andrew Looney's Reply:

> It happens after. James Baxter just makes everyone feel good. So if a Creeper shows you, you play it, and you draw a new card immediately. Then, after all that, the Creeper discard phase occurs. So if a problem shows up while James Baxter is around, he gets rid of it for you, along with any other problems! He’s just great.

Comment: To clarify, Creepers are played immediately when they are drawn and a card drawn to replace them in the hand, so the card does end up in play, albeit after the Action that would destroy it.

Comment: Interesting.  I asked the question to QA@looneylabs.com.

Comment: The important part is "James Baxter just makes everyone feel good"